# How do you download an external javascript library dependency from javascript?

Tags: javascript

Scenario:

I have a user configurable script. For example, code path `A` uses vanilla javascript, path `B` uses `jquery`.

**Code**

```
function MyFunction(choice) {
    if (choice == a) {
      //do some stuff
    }

    if (choice == b) {
        // somehow load jquery
        // do stuff that depends on jquery being loaded
    }
}
```

My confusion is in path `b`. `Jquery` is not on the page by default (i.e. there isn't a `<script src="cdn.jquery.com"></script>` anywhere on the page). But the code in path B needs it to function. Is it possible to load JQuery and then execute the rest of the code?

Comment: jQuery actually uses ajax in the `$.getScript` function to reliably fire an `onload` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the DOM and simply add the script to the `head` (or anywhere else). That's how Facebook, Google Analytics/Plus and many others work.

Here's an example of Analytics code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-id-here', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Let's analyze the relevant lines:

```
a=s.createElement(o)
```

when added the parameters in becomes:

```
a=document.createElement('script')
```

Then this part:

```
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async=1;
a.src=g;
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
```

looks for where in the document are other scripts located (line 1), sets it to async load (line 2), sets the source to the `g` parameter which is `'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'`, and finally it inserts it (line 4).

---

Here's a simple example with an `onload` listener so you know when it's ready:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = 1;
script.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
script.onload = function(){
  alert('script loaded!');
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: So, once I add it to the head, Is there a good way to check when it's downloaded and I can run the rest of my code?

Comment: You should be able to use `onload` and `onreadystatechange` to check whether it's loaded. Added a live example so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `<script>` tag and append it to the DOM, like so:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/path/to/my/script.js';

document.body.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function () {
  console.log('Ready!');
  // Write your code that needs jQuery inside here
};
```

But this should only be looked at as a temporary solution... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.
Just because you have jQuery already loaded on your code, doesn't mean you have to use it. You can do both. And your problem is you need to have jQuery on your page! Put this is your `head` element: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
I think that solves your problem. If not, please give more detail. Good luck!